Only change size of first character in text?
Does anyone know how we can change the font size of only the first character of the text in Swift UI?
I tried concatenating two separate texts but that didn't work out well when text is multiline.
 HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                
                Text(firstCharacter)
                    .font(Font.custom("PlayfairDisplayRoman-Bold", size: 46, relativeTo: .largeTitle))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .blur(radius: blurRadius)
                    .opacity(opacity)
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 1.0)) {
                            blurRadius = 0
                            opacity = 1.0
                        }
                    }
                Text(remainingText)
                    .font(Font.custom("PlayfairDisplayRoman-Bold", size: 36, relativeTo: .largeTitle))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .blur(radius: blurRadius)
                    .opacity(opacity)
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 1.0)) {
                            blurRadius = 0
                            opacity = 1.0
                        }
                    }

            }


Is there any proper way?
im trying to achieve:


"I tried concatenating two separate texts but that didn't work out well when text is multiline." Please explain how it didn't work out well.

added screenshot

I see. You are not really "concatenating" the texts. You're just putting them in a HStack.

idk, i'm a newbie. didn't found anything on google and thats what chatgpt suggested. do you know a way?

You can concatenate the Texts using the + operator like this:
let text = "Do not forget to rest!"
let firstCharacter = text.prefix(1)
let remainingText = text.dropFirst()

let combinedTexts = 
    Text(firstCharacter)
        .font(Font.custom("", size: 46, relativeTo: .largeTitle))
    +
    Text(remainingText)
        .font(Font.custom("PlayfairDisplayRoman-Bold", size: 36, relativeTo: .largeTitle))

Then put all the common modifiers between the two texts on combinedTexts.
combinedTexts
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    .foregroundColor(.primary)
    .padding()
    .blur(radius: blurRadius)
    .opacity(opacity)
    .onAppear {
        withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 1.0)) {
            blurRadius = 0
            opacity = 1.0
        }
    }

